# C# client how to pass subsititution variables to sendgrid marketing template?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

There is a pre-defined marketing template, and the relevant part of the template looks like this:

> Hi [%first_name | Dear Fan%], xxxxxx

There are so many different syntax for sendgrid template variable substitution out there, it's just very confusing. For example, I've seen [%variable_name%], {{variable_name}}, -variable_name- and <%variable_name%>

how do I pass substitution/personalization/template data (just to list the different names I've seen that appears to refer to the same thing) from the C# client to the template?

Comment: Stupid question, but do you 100% need marketing templates and not transactional ones?

Comment: @AndreyStukalin, no it's a good one. But we don't create those templates, we're given those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you use the official SendGrid Nuget package. In that case you could use the `MailHelper` class and its methods `CreateSingleTemplateEmail`, `CreateSingleTemplateEmailToMultipleRecipients` or `CreateMultipleTemplateEmailsToMultipleRecipients` depending on your needs. In the simplest case it should be something like this.

```
            var client = new SendGridClient(ApiKey);

            var dynamicTemplateData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"first_name", "John"},
                {"last_name", "Snow"},
            };

            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmail(
                new EmailAddress("from@test.com"),
                new EmailAddress("to@test.com"),
                "d-template-id",
                dynamicTemplateData);


            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

The above method works surely for transactional templates and I am not 100% sure about marketing ones.

Comment: Here is the unit test from the sendgrid official repo that shows how to use this. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/e66855a48e17c99fb8c7b06b58e96c62525fc303/tests/SendGrid.Tests/Helpers/Mail/MailHelperTests.cs#L22-L41=